# Web api not found after deployed in server

Tags: angularjs, api, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api-routing

I've deployed (with port 9021 and site name Production) an Angularjs Web API application on a test server, and when I hit the URL

```
http://localhost:9021/api/Item/GeAreas?P_Id=US99
```

on the test server, I successfully get a response from the Web API.

This is the code for the api call:

```
 function getAreas(P_Id) { 
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://ps-test.aars/api/Item/GetAreas', 
        // url: 'http://ps-test.aars/Production/api/Item/GetAreas', // error msg: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                                             /Production/api/Item/GetAreas?P_Id=US99 
            params: { P_Id: P_Id },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'dataType': 'json' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.Areas = response.data;             
            }, function errorCallback(response) { }             
        });
    }
```

`web.config`:

```
 <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
 </handlers>
```

When I hit the URL:

```
http://ps-test.aars/Production/Summary.html?P_Id=US99
```

on my local system, I get an error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /api/Item/GetAreas?P_Id=US99

Not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to append port number to your url in the api call code like below

```
 url: 'http://ps-test.aars:9021/api/Item/GetArea'
```

Answer (score 0):

this depends on how you've setup the IIS application on the production server and what URL it is responding to.

Go to your production server, go to IIS, find your application, open it from IIS and it will open in a browser showing you the base URL it's setup to use. Simply add the rest after it. This will work when you run the API from the actual server it's deployed to.

Then you need to call it from your machine so you will need to make sure you are allowed to hit it from your machine. If you're not, then you need to open the port and make sure your machine is allowed to access that production server.

Going from local to production i never straight forward, I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other web.config files on the production server that could be interfering?

I had a Web API 2 project published in a sub-folder of a domain name, which hosted its own ASP.net project. The web.config from that main application was inherited into the web.config of the Web API 2 project, which interfered with routing. Probably because of the use of the URL Rewrite module. To solve the problem I [stopped web.config inheritance completely](http://www.dondraper.com/2010/02/how-to-stop-inheritance-of-webconfig-files/) in the main project.

```
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> 
    <system.web> 
    … 
    </system.web> 
  </location>
```

Not sure if this is your issue, but it's one thing to look at.